# Is it possible to create a one-directional IEqualityComparer?

Tags: c#, linq

Duplicate Edit: Not a duplicate since all the information that was delivered in the responses is already contained in the question. I was wondering if anyone knew a workaround or at least the expected behavior and that question has not been answered...

(Follow Up question to my last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55567057/how-do-i-groupby-from-two-lists))

I'm trying to use .GroupJoin() to map a list of keys to another list of keys, except it's also a match if the keys are equal after ignoring capitalization or certain escape-sequences.

For example:

I have a key called `"ABCD"` in my first list. A list of "Equals" could consist of: `{"ABCD", "AbCd", "AB_MINUS_CD", "ab_PLUS_cd"}`.

My custom "Equals" checks against a pre-defined list of Escape sequences:

Equals:

```
public bool Equals(string firstKey, string escapedKey)
{
    int counter = 0;
    while (escapedKey.Count(x => x == '_') >= 2)
    {
        CharacterMaping mapping = Mappings.ElementAt(counter);
        escapedKey = escapedKey.Replace(mapping, "");
    }

    return String.Equals(firstKey, escapedKey, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
}
```

GroupJoin:

```
IEnumerable<KeyMapping> keyMappings = cleanKeys.GroupJoin(
    escapedKeys,
    c => c,
    e => e,
    (c, result) => new KeyMapping(c, result),
    _keyComparer);
```

Hoever, I see two problems with this:

1. To Implement `IEqualityComparer<string>` I also need to implement `GetHashCode()`. My assumption right now is that hashing is considered faster than Equals so it first checks for Equality of HashCodes and only if the HashCodes are equal ( = Equality is possible ) it also checks for Equality using `Equals();` Since a successful Hash doesn't also automatically mean equality (collisions are possible after all) I might be able to hack around it for my case by simple making `GetHashCode()` return the same value, regardless of the input.
2. By definition an `IEqualityComparer` (or rather any type of equivalence relation needs to be symmetric: `a == b => b == a`. I am using `IEqualityComparer` because `GroupJoin` requires it but I am obviously trying to write a one-directional `IEqualityComparer`: `a == b` does not imply `b == a`. I am, again, just assuming that `GroupJoin` calls `Equals(a, b)` with the element of the first list as the first argument but it would be good to know if I have to reverse it :p

Honestly, I am trying to make something work that is just not meant to be that way and I should probably use a different, more manual, loop-based approach but I am really intrigued and wondering if someone can tell me, how this stuff works internally.

Comment: `Equals` should be commutative operation, with this request the contract will be broken...

Comment: it is very important that you follow the rules when building an equality comparison. You **must** meet the conditions that `A==A` is always true, that `A==B` and `B==A` always have the same value, and that if `A==B` and `B==C` then `A==C`. That is, it must be a reflexive, symmetric and transitive relation, also known as an equivalence relation. If you do not do this, bad things can and will happen. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54025578/need-help-understanding-unexpected-behavior-using-linq-join-with-hashsett/54028123#54028123 for an example.